# Splitting and saving data into seperate dataframes

Tags: r, split

I am using the split function and wanting to save each split into a new dataframe. Right now the data is in one single dataframe side by side.

```
a<-split(SQLCommand, SQLCommand$FactsetDate)
```

Comment: see `?list2env`

Comment: Can you give some example data? Do you only have one large dataframe where different columns correspond to different dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation of split says, `a` is now a list of splitted objects.

If you splitted only in 2 you can do:

```
a1 <- a[[1]]
a2 <- a[[2]]
```